# Google Maps v1: Map shows on emulator, but only grey tiles on test device

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a reviewed all posts and answers, **but simple question..**.

When using a TEST device, uploaded via Eclipse, should I use the API-Key from the debug.Keystore or do I need one from my app keystore?

My app works fine when using an emulator, but I get grey tiles when testing on a test HTC device.

Comment: OK... The API Key for "debug" ONLY works on emulators. If you use Eclise to load the software in "debug mode" to a handset, you will get tiles, not a map. 
If you update the mapview with a "release" API key, then use Eclipse "EXPORT" to create an apk file, copy this to the sd card on the handset, then use an installer app (download free from Google Play) to install it on the phone IT WORKS!!!

Comment: **App development stage use your System debug.keystore value.** **App Relesing stage use your app debug.keystore value** Steps and detailed answer i already give here **[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987374/maps-is-working-on-development-stage-but-not-release-stage/17987498#17987498](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987374/maps-is-working-on-development-stage-but-not-release-stage/17987498#17987498)**